# My ListView backgrounds go black during scrolling - how to fix?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, colors

Ive specified white backgrounds for pretty much all widgets and it works, except when scrolling. The background container goes black during scrolling resulting in annoying flickering.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803028/gets-flickering-layouts-background-while-scrolling-the-listview-in-android

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You will need to use the `setCacheColorHint()` method of ListView.

Example: `list.setCacheColorHint(yourBackColor);`

Explanation of the issue and solution [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

Comment: Just wanted to add this in case someone else finds this thread.

I used 'android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"' on the ListView layout to fix.

Answer (score 4):

ScrollingCache="false" in your activity's *.xml file for the list object should do the trick, too.

Comment: That's a terrible idea, it makes scrolling/flinging the list a lot slower.

Comment: Oh, good to know! For me it always worked well. Nevertheless, I will avoid this in the future and use the setCacheColorHint() solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put background on the top and no highlight or other bad effects simple and no need of hint or cache
in listview layout
`android:background="#000000"` for black background or `android:background="#FFFFFF"` for white

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testscheck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/ics"
        android:textSize="14sp"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by making the background color of the cells the same color as the ListView, so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"> <---- Background color of ListView
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"> <--- Background color of the cell

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/projects_cover_row_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/projects_cover_row_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/projects_image_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

that completely got rid of the problem for me and seems like the best solution