# Gets Flickering layout's background while scrolling the listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

while scroll the listview, the Layouts background gets flickering. that is the layout is has a background image. this image will gets invisible and reload all the time while scrolling. how to rectify this? Any Idea?

Note: its happening for inbuilt android Array Adapter too.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_value));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat/2706944), esp. the `android:cacheColorHint` part.

Answer (score 2):

The official Android site has a [detailed discussion on this issue](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html), I believe.

Comment: Essentially the same answer as the two replies by tanchenko and ZoharAdar anyway,

Answer (score 2):

to void the flickering image background try to add  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in the ListView

Comment: works great. The issue has been solved on Android 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to it from Java (code) side, this helps: `listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);`